# Android- crop square image inside bounding box on surfaceview

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-crop

I am trying to crop image inside bounding box from camera preview and display in a activity. I have a surfaceview and a square imageview on top of it. I have to capture image that appears only inside imageview. Following is my cropping code, No idea as to what is wrong here,Please help

```
                int width  = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
                int height = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();
                int newWidth = (height > width) ? width : height;
                int newHeight = (height > width)? height - ( height - width) : height;
                int x = (width - height) / 2;
                x = (x < 0)? 0: x;
                int y = (height - width) / 2;
                y = (y < 0)? 0: y;
                Bitmap cropImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotatedBitmap, x, y,newWidth, newHeight);
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you checked the captured bitmap (before cropping)? Is it fine?

Comment: @Sahil   yes it is fine. I get the complete image of preview. but I need to capture image that is only inside the square view

Comment: The code looks fine. Could you add breakpoints or get logs to see what are width/height values you're getting?
And what's the output bitmap that you're getting? same as original bitmap?

Comment: @Sahil, yes I did and I got height=2560 and width=1920

Comment: What is the result? Is the app crashing?
A bitmap of this size is going to be around 20MB and then another bitmap, i.e. the cropped bitmap is going to be another 16MB.
I hope you're not getting an OOM exception.

Comment: @Sahil  To be specific, I need to get a 300*300 dp square image from centre of surfaceview. But when the image is cropped, it is more than required size

Comment: No I am not getting any exception, the cropped image gets saved to sd card, but it is slightly bigger in size than 300*300 dp square image

Comment: Oh.. okay.. in that case... 
        int finalWidth, finalHeight; 
finalWidth = finalHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
Now instead of newWidth and newHeight, use finalWidth and finalHeight.
You will need to calculate x and y accordingly.

Comment: oh! alright. Will try now and let you know.. give me 2 min. I am sorry,i am not very clear with calculating x and y. Could you please let me know

Comment: Shouldn't x and y be calculated from centre of surfaceview ??, as of now, it is taking 300*300 dp square photofrom top left. I should take x and y from centre and it would fix.

Comment: @Sahil, Thank you so much, its working, it cropped 300*300 from top, i just took x and y cordinates from centre and its working. Thanks a lot